# IE7, Coldfusion, and cfselect/select

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-7, coldfusion-9

I would like `ColdFusion.Event.callBindHandlers('mySelect',null,'change');`, or something similar, to initiate an ajax request on an onChange event for a select/cfselect in IE7.

To get the value of a `<select>` in IE7 you have to use code like this (at least to the best of my knowledge)

js

```
function $(id){
     return document.getElementById(id);    
}
function getText(){
     alert($("mySelect").options[$("mySelect").selectedIndex].text);
}
```

html

```
<select id="mySelect">
     <option>myOption</option>
</select>
```

I think my problem is the Coldfusion JavaScript libraries use `mySelect.value` instead of the convoluted wreck that is required for IE7.

Comment: if it's a bug, report to http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html .  Are you using CF8 or 9?

Comment: if `ColdFusion.Event.callBindHandlers` doesn't work for you, try jQuery instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfselect name="location" onchange="doSomething()">....</cfselect>

getLocation = function(){
  return ColdFusion.getElementValue('location');    
 }

doSomething = function(){
 if(getLocation() != ""){
   // do some ajax stuff here since we have our cfselect values

 } 
}
```

Comment: `getLocation()` doesn't work for me in IE7, is this only me or do you have this problem as well?